# Draw an arc on circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I am developing an application in which I have to show a filled arc on my circle which will indicate the selected time.
I have attached an image for specifying what I exactly want to ask:-

[image]

Please help me  in how to draw arc on circle.

Any suggestions will be  highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729690/draw-part-of-a-circle)

Comment: can you please help me writing whole code for this.