# Using Core Plot to show the selected Time Period in circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, core-plot, cppiechart

I am developing an application in which I have to show the selected time in my clock image.
Description:-
What I exactly want to say it I am having a image of circle. Now according to the selected time I want that portion to be filled in some other color on my circle image.
Please help me in doing this.
I am stuck here.

I have attached the image that will describe more what I exactly want to do.
I also tried it with doing it with pie-chart but area  showing  not giving proper time.
Please please help me.

[image]

In this image it shows time 1:am to 6:am
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You asked this yesterday and were pointed at some sample code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519836/draw-an-arc-on-circle

Comment: @Warren Burton: The difference this time is that the questioner is now asking about Core Plot. (This wasn't clear to me, either, until I Googled the “cppiechart” tag and found it to be a class from that framework.) So it is a different question; the other one was more general. I have edited this question to clarify and emphasize this distinction.

Comment: Do you want a solution to this specific problem or do you want to use cppiechart (which seems a little overkill for this)

Comment: @Warren I want the solution of this problem whether using pie-chart or not.

Comment: @Warren if you know please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want above (not using coreplot). Place this code in the relevant drawRect/drawInContext method.

Not at mac so not 100% sure it will compile. Should be close. Also might be out by 90

```
#include <math.h>

CGFloat radius = 100;
//CGFloat pi = 3.1415927; //comes for free in math.h

//draw underlying circle;
UIBezierPath *basecircle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,radius*2,radius*2)];
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
[basecircle fill];

CGFloat starttime = pi/6; //1 pm = 1/6 rad
GFloat  endtime = pi;  //6 pm = 1 rad

//draw arc
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius,radius);
UIBezier *arc = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; //empty path
[arc moveToPoint:center];
CGPoint next;
next.x = radius + radius * sin(starttime);
next.y = radius + radius * cos(starttime);
[arc moveToPoint:next]; //go one end of arc
[arc addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:starttime endAngle:endtime clockwise:YES]; //add the arc
[arc moveToPoint:center]; //back to center

[[UIColor yellowColor] set];
[arc fill];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I executed this code.It gets compile properly but when I execute it nothing comes on screen.

Comment: @please can you see why nothing is coming on screen

Comment: How are you using it? CALayer , UIView? Is the layer/view in a hiearchy? . Is the frame of the view at least 2*radius in size.