# Animating Circle's endAngle with CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have some UIView with drawrect code for drawing pie:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        CGRect parentViewBounds = self.bounds;
        CGFloat x = CGRectGetWidth(parentViewBounds)/2;
        CGFloat y = CGRectGetHeight(parentViewBounds)/2;

        // Get the graphics context and clear it
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);


        // define line width
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 4.0);


        CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents( [someColor CGColor]));
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
        CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, 100,  radians(270), radians(270), 0); // 27
        CGContextClosePath(ctx);
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

But when I try to animate "endAngle" property after drawing, it doesn't work:

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"endAngle"];
theAnimation.duration=1;
theAnimation.repeatCount=1;
theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:270];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:60];
[[self.layer presentationLayer] addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make an animation then you should look into using Core Animation for the drawing. It makes animation much simpler.

Have a look at [this great tutorial on making a custom animatable pie chart with Core Animation](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/). I'm sure that you can modify it to get what you want.

If it seems to complicated to you then you can have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651797/608157) to ["Draw part of a circle"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3729690/608157) which draws a pie chart shape by making a very wide stroke of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Several things. You can't use a CAAnimation to animate drawing that you do in a drawRect method like that.

Second, if you did use a CAShapeLayer, you could animate changes to the path that's installed in the layer, but you need to make sure that the path has the same number and type of control points for all steps in the animation.

CGPath arc commands use different numbers of control points to draw different angles. Thus, you can't change the angle of the arc and animate it.

What you have to do is to install a path that's the full length of your arc, and then animate changes to the shape layer's strokeStart and/or strokeEnd properties. Those properties cause the path to omit the first part/last part of the path from the drawing. I daresay the tutorial David linked to on the animatable pie chart uses that technique.