# Drawing a circle ,filled different parts with different color

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am a novice ios programmer.In one of my project i need to draw a circle in which different portion of the circle would be filled up with different colors.I can draw the circle.But i am not being able to determine the different portion of the circle and fill them with different color.Here is an screenshot to clarify what i want to draw.[image: circle with different color]

A help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a pie chart. Why not use [Core plot](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) for this?

Comment: For people to give you answers appropriate for your implementation, you might want to let us know if you're using the CoreGraphics functions (those functions that start with `CGContext`) in your own `drawRect`, or using the `UIBezierPath` `stroke` method, or using `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: **Core plot** is a best platform to creating chart in to ios app. But take a look bellow github amazing Sample Code:- https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oTHcE.png)

Comment: @Rob actually i am using core graphics functions like CGContext.

Comment: I can also recommend ios Charts https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `UIBezierPath` which has a method `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` where you can specify radius, center and angles. The code could look like this which draws a quarter of a circle in green:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2.f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2.f);
CGFloat radius = center.x - 10.f;

UIBezierPath *portionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[portionPath moveToPoint:center];
[portionPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:0.f endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
[portionPath closePath];

[[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
[portionPath fill];

UIBezierPath *portionPath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[portionPath1 moveToPoint:center];
[portionPath1 addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
[portionPath1 closePath];

[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[portionPath1 fill];
```

Of course you can also consider to use a library like [CorePlot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Comment: it works perfectly for one portion.but how can i continue it with other portions??I did the same process for other portions changing start angle and & end angle .but is not working desirably

Comment: Just play with the angles and colors. Center and radius should always be the same. You would have to calculate the angle of each portion and then loop through all portions increasing the start- and endangles.

Comment: I thought that too.but something wrong about my angle.could you just show me another portions angle calculation.I tried like this for the next portion [startAngle:M_PI_2  endAngle:M_PI]

Comment: I just added a second portion.

Comment: That was absolutely helpful.Thanks a lot @Karl

Answer (score 3):

**we have 6 class**

**CircleViewController.h, CircleViewController.m, GraphView.h, GraphView.h, CirclePart.h, CirclePart.m**

**CirclePart.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CirclePart : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat startDegree;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat endDegree;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *partColor;

-(id)initWithStartDegree:(CGFloat)startDegree endDegree:(CGFloat)endDegree partColor:(UIColor*)partColor;

@end
```

**CirclePart.m**

```
#import "CirclePart.h"

@implementation CirclePart

-(id)initWithStartDegree:(CGFloat)startDegree endDegree:(CGFloat)endDegree partColor:(UIColor*)partColor
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.startDegree = startDegree;
        self.endDegree = endDegree;
        self.partColor = partColor;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**GraphView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CirclePart.h"

@interface GraphView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint centrePoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat radius;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lineWidth;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *circleParts;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame CentrePoint:(CGPoint)centrePoint radius:(CGFloat)radius lineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth circleParts:(NSArray*)circleParts;

@end
```

**GraphView.m**

```
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation GraphView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame CentrePoint:(CGPoint)centrePoint radius:(CGFloat)radius lineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth circleParts:(NSArray*)circleParts
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.centrePoint = centrePoint;
        self.radius = radius;
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        self.circleParts = circleParts;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [self drawCircle];
}

- (void)drawCircle {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, _lineWidth);

    for(CirclePart *circlePart in _circleParts)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _centrePoint.x, _centrePoint.y);

        CGContextAddArc(context, _centrePoint.x , _centrePoint.y, _radius, [self radians:circlePart.startDegree], [self radians:circlePart.endDegree], 0);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, circlePart.partColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    }
}

-(float) radians:(double) degrees {
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}


@end
```

**CircleViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CircleViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**CircleViewController.m**

```
#import "CircleViewController.h"
#import "GraphView.h"
#import "CirclePart.h"

@interface CircleViewController ()

@end

@implementation CircleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CirclePart *part1 = [[CirclePart alloc] initWithStartDegree:0 endDegree:120 partColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    CirclePart *part2 = [[CirclePart alloc] initWithStartDegree:120 endDegree:250 partColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    CirclePart *part3 = [[CirclePart alloc] initWithStartDegree:250 endDegree:360 partColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    NSArray *circleParts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:part1, part2, part3, nil];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
    CGPoint circleCenter = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2);

    GraphView *graphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:rect CentrePoint:circleCenter radius:80 lineWidth:2 circleParts:circleParts];
    graphView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    graphView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    graphView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    [self.view addSubview:graphView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple question of trigonometry. Figure out the angle you need for the pie portion (pie slice percent time 360 degrees), then you move to the center. Line to the circle edge at an appropriate angle, arc to the next side of the pie slice for the arc angle that you need, then line back to the center.

Alternatively, you could use [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) to make pie charts for you .