# Create a circle with multiple color

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I m Developing an iphone app and i want to create a circle with multiple color. Like below image

[image]

m using draw rect method for drawing a circle but no luck with multiplecolors.

can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269586/drawing-a-circle-filled-different-parts-with-different-color

Comment: @iPatel i can draw with like piechart but i want to draw like in image  not clock wise. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need it to scale? Can you just use a `UIImageView` with a png file?

Comment: ya i can use but later i also want to change this color slowly and morphing@godel9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this effect using [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) with circular mask. Sample code (assuming you use it in some view controller):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CAGradientLayer *glayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    glayer.frame = CGRectMake(60.0f, 60.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    glayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                      (__bridge id)[UIColor cyanColor].CGColor,
                      (__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,
                      (__bridge id)[UIColor purpleColor].CGColor,
                      (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                      (__bridge id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor,
                      (__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor];
    glayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    CAShapeLayer *shLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [shLayer setPath:CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200), NULL)];
    [glayer setMask:shLayer];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: glayer];
}
```

Note that `colors` and `locations` properties of CAGradientLayer are animatable, so you can easily add animated effects using that approach

Comment: i will try and if its done i will accept your answer surely Thanks

Comment: @Vladimir your solution works like charm form me. can you please help me in one more things? I want to change this color slowly slowly. Thanks in advance

Comment: hi @Vladimir can you please give me anser on below question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016213/how-to-change-color-of-cagradientlayer-like-screensaver   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use CGGradientRef and CGContextDrawLinearGradient from QuartzCore (do not forgot to add QuartzCore to your project and import it)

create gradient You can using something like that something like that (in UIView subclass):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGGradientRef gradient;
        CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();;

        //5 is for count of colors
        CGFloat parts[5] = { .2, .4, .6, .8, .1 };

        //colors for each part, so 5 parts by 4 each (r,g,b,a for each part in range 0 - 1, 1 is for 255 in regular rgb space, and alpha as usual)
        CGFloat components[20] = {
            .3, .24, .1, 1,
            .3, .2, .7, 1,
            .3, .84, .2, 1,
            .3, .24, .3, 1,
            .1, .5, .38, 1
        };

        gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgb, components, parts, 5);

        CGPoint top = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), 0.0f);
        CGPoint bottom = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), rect.size.height);

        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, top, bottom, 0);

        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

        //round shape you can archive by Vladimir's solution
        CAShapeLayer *shLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [shLayer setPath:CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectInset(rect, 5, 5), NULL)];
        [self.layer setMask:shLayer];
}
```

Comment: If you decide to draw using CGContext you can clip it using CGContextClip function, not using layers for that. However using CGContext you won't be able to apply animations to gradient easily