# How can I draw a circle in iOS with a custom amount filled with a colour?

Tags: ios, xcode

Can someone suggest me a way to draw a circle with a custom amount filled with a colour in iOS?

Comment: What do you mean exactly. Please share screen shot of expected output.

Comment: Please search before asking. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729690/draw-part-of-a-circle) a hit from searching.

Comment: you shold look at this https://github.com/Marxon13/M13ProgressSuite

Answer (score 0):

1. create a button on the main.storyboard
2. create a new class and assign this new class to new button
3. within the new class add this code

import UIKit

```
@IBDesignable class YourNewClass: UIButton {

  @IBInspectable var fillColor:UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
  @IBInspectable var isAddButton:Bool = true

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
    fillColor.setFill()
    path.fill()
```

}
}

I learned this while following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

p.s. once you 'draw' a circle button, you can always select the color in the attributes inspector