# How to create a custom circled UIView with two different colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, draw

Is there a way to create a circled UIView with two different colors, 
like this:

[image: circle example]

The circle should be divided as you can see on the image (border).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `UIView` and implement the `drawRect:` method.

Here is code to draw a circle to get you started:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]));
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

also, take a look at [how to draw part of a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729690/draw-part-of-a-circle)